# How to close connection in memcache explicitly

Tags: java, windows, memcached, spymemcached

I am trying to close a memcached connection to start a new one. But i am unable to find any suitable method in memcached.
I am closing previous connection because it tries to keep reconnecting to failed server.

I am using spymemcached 2.8.0 and memcached 1.4.4 for windows.

Comment: Why are you not using connection pool ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a shutdown method in MemcachedClient.